# Python GPU bubble sort

Tags: python, sorting, gpu, numba

I have a sorting but unclearly big data need to sort clearly. Therefore, I want to use bubble sort to do it. Likes it.

```
#CPU bubble sort
def CPU_bubble_sort(data):
    for i in range(len(data)): # times
        change = False # Are there any action in this round?
        for i2 in range(len(data)-1): # index
            if data[i2] > data[i2+1]: # complete
                data[i2],data[i2+1] = data[i2+1],data[i2] # change
                change = True # There have actions in this round.
        if change == False: # if there are not any actions in this round
            break # It's mean sorting is finish.
    return data
```

Now, I want to use GPU from numba to do it quickly.

```
from numba import cuda
import numpy as np

#Call gpu sort function
def call_bubble_sort(data):
    #GPU deploy
    threads_per_block = 512 # threads
    blocks_per_grid = int(len(data) / 2 / threads_per_block) # blocks
    if len(data) / 2 % threads_per_block == 0:
        pass
    else: 
        blocks_per_grid += 1 
    #complete
    gpu_data = cuda.to_device(data) # data copy to gpu
    change = cuda.to_device(np.bool_(False)) # Are there any action in this round?
    for i in range(len(data)): #max times
        gpu_step = cuda.to_device(np.bool_(i%2)) # odd steps or even steps
        GPU_BubbleSort[blocks_per_grid,threads_per_block](gpu_data,gpu_step,change)
        cuda.synchronize() #wait GPU in this round
        if i % 2 == 0: 
            continue
        elif change.copy_to_host() == False: # if there are not any actions in this round
            break # can stop
        change = cuda.to_device(np.bool_(False)) # next rounds
    return gpu_data.copy_to_host()

@cuda.jit
def GPU_BubbleSort(data,step,change):
    idx = cuda.threadIdx.x + cuda.blockDim.x * cuda.blockIdx.x # thread num
    idx = idx * 2 + 1 # data odd nums
    #sort
    if idx < len(data): # threads to act
        if step == False: # even rounds
            if data[idx] < data[idx-1]: #complete left first
                change = True # Action in this turn
                data[idx] , data[idx-1] = data[idx-1] , data[idx] # change
        else: #odd rounds
            #complete right
            if idx+1 >= len(data): #if out of the data range
                pass # do nothing
            elif data[idx] > data[idx+1]: # complete right
                data[idx] , data[idx+1] = data[idx+1] , data[idx] # change
                change = True # Action in this turn
```

I think that 'change' is a single variable, so every threads are eager to update it if in demand. In other words, the variable won't be updated if nobody get it.
However, this way is fail. I want to know how to create the sharing variable in a grid, or are there anyway to get the same effect?

I'm poor at English. I'm sorry if I had offended.

Comment: Why did you choose bubble sort if you want to sort efficiently? There are much faster sorting algorithms. The most common are mergesort, quicksort, or even radix sort if you are only sorting numerical arrays.

Comment: Accroding to the first sentence, the data is not very irregular. For examaple: 1 2 3 5 4.
So, I think that bubble sort which can stop is the best way in this situation,especially multiprocesses. 
Following Insert Sort , it's the best way from single process in this case, but it not support multiprocesses.

In fact , please share your valuable feedback with me.

Comment: I think it would be hard to parallelize radix sort, which would probably be the fastest sort.  In fact, radix sort is so fast that even an unparallelized version might still be faster than your GPU version. I think it's worth benchmarking. That being said, I would suggest looking at Timsort. It's a variant of mergesort (hybrid with insert sort), and merge sort is very easy to parallelize. Timsort also works especially well on inputs that are already almost sorted (contrary to naive quicksort). It is, however, a bit harder to implement that common sorts (but far from being impossible).

Comment: Why do you implement that yourself/manually in the first place? There are libraries for that and they are often very optimized. CUB for example contains a Radix sort that is highly optimized and very hard to beat. It is based on the state of the art algorithms (and several decades of research/tests). Note that most sorting algorithms are not very efficient on GPUs and this is a pretty hard problem. You can tune the radix for better efficiency. I expect the CUB algorithm running in O(n) to be much faster than your O(n**2) bubble sort. Especially for "big data"!

Comment: @BlackBeans I think Timsort is hard to implement efficiently on GPUs. GPUs sorting algorithm often need to be deeply redesigned so to be efficient. A good example is Quicksort. Many proposal has been made to optimize it on GPUs but it is still pretty inefficient. Bitonic sort and Radix sort are known to be quite efficient on GPU once optimized. Bitonic sort is GPU-friendly since it is SIMD-friendly (critical point to get an efficient GPU code) but it add significant work compared to Radix sort and so in the and it is not so fast for huge datasets.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I agree with you on the fact that the best solution would probably be to rely on specialized highly-optimized libraries, as it's probably faster and easier than implementing an algorithm by hand. However, I think that one can reach a pretty decent result quite easily with mergesort, as it is quite efficient in practice (not close to radix sort, but still quite good) and it's very easy to implement for a GPU. I mentioned that because the OP seemed like they wanted to implement a sorting algorithm...

Comment: @BlackBeans A merge sort will surely be faster than a bubble-sort, but a naive merge is not SIMD friendly and in actually hard to parallelize (especially the final merges that are the most expensive). Bitonic merge are the way to do that in a SIMD-friendly way (and so in parallel). You can see the Bitonic-sort as a SIMD-friendly variant of the merge-sort.

Comment: Excuse me. I'm a practical program rookie. Most of the knowledge are just learn in school. Therefore, I think that multiprocesses is better than single process(excpet sharing varible), and GPU better than CPU because of number of threads. So, I searched how to use GPU heavily. And then, I also thinks that this case will stop fast with Bubble Sort,the round of steps is better than the others.
Now, accroding to the situation, which one I can follow or research? Thanks for help.

Comment: Is your primary goal with this effort to learn how to write a sort algorithm with numba.cuda or to run an accelerated sort on GPUs? If the latter, perhaps you could use one of the existing implementations?

Comment: I see. Before sorting, I'll complete the data which in class by GPU. Originally, I want to sort with key immediately after complete. It can control by myself easily. Now, I'll try to search how to use existing implementations. Thanks everyone.